# VersionOne: Report on Backlog Items, tasks, defects with Attachments in C# V1 API/JSON

Tags: json, api, versionone

How would you query VersionOne (V1) to build a report that contains (Backlog Items with assoicated tasks, defects and especially **Attachments** in C# for a given Project? Does anyone have **C# V1 API/JSON example** on how to do this?  I need the the part that queries VersioOne and extracts the Attachment to a directory.  I can do the reporting part.

Thanks,

Remy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using any C# HTTP library you like. Submit a query such as the following to `~/query.v1` . The query text may in a POST body or in a GET url parameter named `query`:

```
where:
  Name: Whatever Project You Want
from: Scope
select:
  - Name
  - from: Workitems:PrimaryWorkitem
    select:
      - AssetType
      - Number
      - from: Attachments
        select:
          - Name
          - Description
          - ContentType
          - Content
      - from: Children:Task
        select:
          - Name
          - Number
          - AssetType
          - from: Attachments
            select:
              - Name
              - Description
              - ContentType
              - Content
```

Above, I select `Attachment.Content` which would yield a base64 blob in the output. The attachment content URLs are not present in any attribute that can be selected by `query.v1`, but you can create them by appending the Attachment id to `~/attachment.v1`

Results will be returned in a straightforward hierarchical JSON response:

```
[
 [
  {
   "_oid":"Scope:57460",
   "Name":"openAgile",
   "Workitems:PrimaryWorkitem": [
    {
      "_oid":"Story:83524",
      "AssetType":"Story",
      "Number":"S-08114",
      "Attachments":[],
      "Subs":[],
      "Children:Task": [
        {
          "_oid":"Task:86578",
          "Name":"Test Integration in Atlanta",
          "Number":"TK-11051",
          "AssetType":"Task"
        },
        {
          "_oid":"Task:86581",
          "Name":"Install In our Production environment",
          "Number":"TK-11052",
          "AssetType":"Task"
        },
        {
          "_oid":"Task:86584",
          "Name":"Document",
          "Number":"TK-11053",
          "AssetType":"Task"
        }
    ]
  },
  ]
  }
 ]
]
```

You may also use the `rest-1.v1` endpoint or our SDK library, but `query.v1` is highly suggested for virtually any report or read-only query that it allows.